# Calculating without running the program

Tags: java

I am asked to name the value for the variable x that the piece of algorithm below will put out after running. I have no idea how to calculate this without actually writing it into an actual Java program. The solution should be 1024. How do I calculate this on paper?

Algorithm:

```
int n = 4;
int x = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
       x += x;
    }
}
System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: I would get a pencil and paper, and walk through the code, writing down the values of x as each loop loops. You don't even have to do all the loops to solve this, as a pattern will/should emerge if you do this. In the future, please show what you *have* done to solve your problem in your question, as this will improve the quality of the question many-fold.

Comment: Just look what happens. There are two loops, one counting from 1 to 4, the other one counting from 1 to the current outer loop variable. The inner statement is thus executed ten times. Combined with the actual statement being executed in the inner loop (`x += x`) you can do the math yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `x += x` *doubles* `x` every time the innermost statement is executed.
The inner loop is executed `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 4 * (4 + 1) / 2 = 10` times. Thus, the result must be `2^10 = 1024`.

For general `n`, it should be something like `2^((n + 1) * n / 2)`.

The fact that `1 + 2 + ... + n = (n + 1) * n / 2` is sometimes called ["Gaussian sum formula"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9Fsche_Summenformel), you should remember it next time you see two nested loops where the range of the inner index depends on the outer index.

Comment: @Andrew Tyukin when the value of x=2 initially then the output is 2048 as opposed to 1024 where x=1. The inner loop is still executed 10 times so how did you get to 2^10 part??

Comment: @sticky_elbows Well, yes, because `2048 = 1024 * 2`? What else did you expect? If you want to treat `x` as a parameter, the explicit formula would be `x * 2 ^ ((n + 1) * n / 2)`, it depends linearly on the initial value of `x`. If you double the initial value of `x`, you get the result that is twice as large.

Comment: Nested loops vs. explicit formula (in Scala): `def q(n: Int, x0: Int): Int = { var x = x0; for (i <- 1 to n) { for (j <- 1 to i) x += x }; x }` vs. `def p(n: Int, x0: Int) = x0 * math.pow(2, (n * n + n) / 2)`, of someone else wants to try it out.

Comment: @Andrew Tyukin it is 2^10 because the x doubles every time or is it because there are 2 nested loops. I just want to know where 2 comes from into this equation. Thanks.

Comment: @sticky_elbows It's because of the `x += x`, which is the same as `x *= 2`. Had it been `x *= b` for some other base `b`, then the formula would have been `x_0 * b ^ ((n + 1) * n / 2)` (where `x_0` is the initial value of `x`).

Comment: @Andrew Tyukin thanks. Now you get my +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

There's few enough iterations that you can literally just write it out and keep a running tally:

```
i = 1

j = 1 to 1
1) x = x + x      2

i = 2

j = 1 to 2
1) x = x + x      4
2) x = x + x      8

i = 3

j = 1 to 3

1) x = x + x     16
2) x = x + x     32
3) x = x + x     64

i = 4

j = 1 to 4

1) x = x + x    128
2) x = x + x    256
3) x = x + x    512
4) x = x + x   1024
```